# Unwind array values in BigQuery/SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, count, google-bigquery

I was trying to unwind array values to different rows in BigQuery/ PSQL.

This is what I have right now ::

```
Col_1                    col_2
A                      array: {1,2,3,4,5}

B                      array: {1,2,3}

C                      array: {4,5,6}
```

I want to convert this as shown below in BigQuery.

```
A          1
A          2
A          3
A          4
A          5
B          1
B          2
B          3
C          4
C          5
C          6
```

Comment: Have you looked at FLATTEN?

Comment: Here is the link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from

Answer (score 1):

Using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" box under "Show Options") you can do:

```
WITH MyTable AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS Col_1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] AS col_2
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B', [1, 2, 3]
  UNION ALL SELECT 'C', [4, 5, 6])
SELECT Col_1, col_2 FROM MyTable t, t.col_2;
+-------+-------+
| Col_1 | col_2 |
+-------+-------+
| A     |     1 |
| A     |     2 |
| A     |     3 |
| A     |     4 |
| A     |     5 |
| B     |     1 |
| B     |     2 |
| B     |     3 |
| C     |     4 |
| C     |     5 |
| C     |     6 |
+-------+-------+
```

Here the "comma" operator is equivalent to a cross join, which has the effect of flattening the repetition. As Pavan points out above, you can also accomplish this in legacy SQL using the [`FLATTEN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from) operator, although the syntax is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bound to BigQuery Legacy SQL - try below

```
SELECT col_1, SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT(col_2, ':'), '{', ''), '}', ''), ',') AS elem 
FROM
  (SELECT 'A' AS col_1, 'array: {1,2,3,4,5}' AS col_2),
  (SELECT 'B' AS col_1, 'array: {1,2,3}' AS col_2),
  (SELECT 'C' AS col_1, 'array: {4,5,6}' AS col_2)
HAVING elem <> 'array'  

col_1   elem     
A       1    
A       2    
A       3    
A       4    
A       5    
B       1    
B       2    
B       3    
C       4    
C       5    
C       6
```